# Activity refreshing/blinking after changing theme in Android Studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to make a switch button that toggles dark/light mode. I've managed to make it work but the only problem is that, after pressing switch button theme changes and activity flickers or activity is restarting/refreshing by it's self. After pressing switch button basically app just starts glitching out. Here's my **`Manifest`** code:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

And here's my **`MainActivity`** code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Switch dark_light;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dark_light = findViewById(R.id.dark_light);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("night", 0);
        Boolean booleanValue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("night_mode", true);
        if(booleanValue){
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            dark_light.setChecked(true);
        }
        dark_light.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    dark_light.setChecked(true);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("night_mode", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }else{
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    dark_light.setChecked(false);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("night_mode", false);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This part of the code seems to be working fine. You may have other bugs in your app.

Comment: I thought about that too. But I don't know what bug can possibly cause this

Comment: Try cleaning up your activity and keeping only the code necessary. Comment out parts of code to see if the issue goes away.